# jenkins fails to build with "No such file or directory"

Tags: ros, buildfarm, message-generation, jenkins

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've [asked about similar issue](http://answers.ros.org/question/62092/catkin_make-started-failing-to-generage-h-from-msg/) that happens on local `catkin_make`.

Now it's solved, but with the same pkgs that I discussed there, I'm seeing similar issue happening on `jenkins` that complains the `.h` file from `.msg` is not found, although the console output implies it is built. Here's the excerpt from [jenkins' output](http://jenkins.willowgarage.com:8080/job/devel-groovy-rqt_common_plugins/ARCH_PARAM=amd64,UBUNTU_PARAM=precise,label=devel/16/console):

```
Executing command 'make'
[  4%] Generating ui_widgets_list.h
[  9%] Generating include/rqt_cpp_common/moc_widgets_list.cxx
Scanning dependencies of target rqt_cpp_common
[ 13%] Building CXX object rqt_common_plugins/rqt_cpp_common/CMakeFiles/rqt_cpp_common.dir/src/rqt_cpp_common/widgets_list.cpp.o
[ 18%] Building CXX object rqt_common_plugins/rqt_cpp_common/CMakeFiles/rqt_cpp_common.dir/include/rqt_cpp_common/moc_widgets_list.cxx.o
Linking CXX shared library ../../devel/lib/librqt_cpp_common.so
[ 18%] Built target rqt_cpp_common
Scanning dependencies of target rqt_cpp_common_gencpp
[ 22%] Generating C++ code from rqt_cpp_common/RouteGps.msg
[ 22%] Built target rqt_cpp_common_gencpp
Scanning dependencies of target rqt_cpp_common_genlisp
[ 27%] Generating Lisp code from rqt_cpp_common/RouteGps.msg
[ 27%] Built target rqt_cpp_common_genlisp
Scanning dependencies of target rqt_cpp_common_genpy
[ 31%] Generating Python from MSG rqt_cpp_common/RouteGps
[ 36%] Generating Python msg __init__.py for rqt_cpp_common
[ 36%] Built target rqt_cpp_common_genpy
:
[ 72%] Generating ui_marble_plugin.h
[ 77%] Generating include/rqt_marble/moc_marble_plugin.cxx
[ 81%] Generating include/rqt_marble/moc_bridge_ros_marble.cxx
Scanning dependencies of target rqt_marble
[ 86%] Building CXX object rqt_common_plugins/rqt_marble/CMakeFiles/rqt_marble.dir/src/rqt_marble/marble_plugin.cpp.o
In file included from /tmp/test_repositories/src_repository/rqt_common_plugins/rqt_marble/include/rqt_marble/marble_plugin.h:42:0,
                 from /tmp/test_repositories/src_repository/rqt_common_plugins/rqt_marble/src/rqt_marble/marble_plugin.cpp:48:
/tmp/test_repositories/src_repository/rqt_common_plugins/rqt_marble/include/rqt_marble/bridge_ros_marble.h:47:37: fatal error: rqt_cpp_common/RouteGps.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

What's wrong?

The rendition of the sources that were used for building: [rqt_cpp_common](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_common_plugins/tree/cc0ba0f421769a998855faaaed8f7b83b023fe13/rqt_cpp_common), [rqt_marble](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_common_plugins/tree/cc0ba0f421769a998855faaaed8f7b83b023fe13/rqt_marble)

By the way, the pkg that tries to refer to the missing `.h` file, `rqt_marble` pkg, is not even released. It just resides within the source repo of the metapkg being built. So I'm not expecting that this particular pkg to be built but I feel I should open a new thread for it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62707/jenkins-fails-to-build-with-%22no-such-file-or-directory%22/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2013-05-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your title is misleading. The problem is not that the file doesn't exist, the problem is that you are missing the dependency on rqt_cpp_common from your rqt_marble CMakeLists.txt in the find_package catkin line.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-05-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-05-14**:
After adding `rqt_cpp_common` in `find_package`, looks like `jenkins` stops failing (the latest build says `unstable`, not `failure`). I also modified the title accordingly.